# Etiquette/protocols/conventions for geocache logs

Tags: geocaching

I realize that it's "only a game", and it doesn't have rigid rules, but there must be some standards that I could follow.

- A year and a half ago I noticed a strange object in a tree, but didn't know what it was.
- Recently, I heard of geocaching, looked at a map, and realized that the object was a cache.
- Later I opened it, but my fingers were too frozen to fill in the log.
- Next spring I might return and complete the log.

Obviously the last date would be acceptable, but would any of the other dates be appropriate for the "official" log date?

Comment: IMO:  You can use all three.  First time-found it but didn't know what it was.  Second time-opened it, but too cold to write.  Third time- 'a charm. ;)  This site https://www.geocaching.com/play might be able to help you more.

Comment: @MikeSchroedel, can you please write that as an answer? It has all that is needed and that allows for upvoting and acceptance by OP.

Comment: @MikeSchroedel, by "three" I assume you mean the last three.  Seeing a cache without realizing what it is doesn't count.  But seeing what one *knows* is a cache is what counts. One can open the cache and retroactively log that earlier date at a much later time.

Comment: @RayButterworth, I think the first one should count because it is what got you interested in the hobby.

Comment: @MikeSchroedel, actually no, it isn't.  I looked into geocaching because I heard someone else frequently mentioning it. In the process of finding out what geocaching is, I looked at a map of local caches and noticed that one was located in my neighbourhood.  It was only then, more than a year after first seeing it, that I realized what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the closest thing to an official answer to your question that I know of is [this geocaching.com blog post](https://www.geocaching.com/blog/2019/06/geocaching-etiquette-201-finding-and-logging/), which says (**boldface** original):

> **Caches can be logged online as “Found” after the geocacher has visited the coordinates and signed the logbook.**

Now, technically, this doesn't necessarily mean that, once you've completed both requirements, you couldn't backdate your find to an earlier date.  But the blog post does go on to say that:

> - When logging a cache online, use the date you attempted the cache. This helps to provide a more accurate view of the cache’s current condition.

(The reason for using the word "attempted" instead of "found" here is presumably because this guideline is meant to apply to all types of online log entries, including "Did Not Find" and "Needs Maintenance" logs.)

---

So, following the guidelines set out in this blog post:

- You should not log the cache as found online before you actually sign the physical logbook.

  (You could, however, post a "Note" or a "Did Not Find" log describing your earlier visit if you want.  Many cache owners like to hear about people visiting their cache even if they fail to find and/or sign it.)
- Once you do revisit the cache and sign the logbook, you may log it as found online.  When doing so, you should *probably* use the date on which you sign the physical logbook.

It's also possible that, if you do post a note saying that you found the cache but couldn't sign the logbook, the cache owner *might* contact you and suggest that you just log the cache as found, even though it's technically against the rules.  In that case, it's up to you whether you want to do that or not.  Some cache owners are quite lenient about such "found but couldn't sign" logs, some are not.

(Personally, I neither encourage nor discourage them on my own caches, but I do try to be strict about my own finds, and will post a note instead if I e.g. forget to bring my pen.  But I feel that, if a cacher personally considers something a find, that's generally fine with me.  I might be stricter about it if I had any caches where getting access to the logbook was particularly difficult by design.)

---

In practice, the date of the online log only matters for two purposes:

1. It tells the cache owner (and anyone else browsing the online logs) about the status of the cache: if you log the cache as found on a particular date, you're communicating that the cache was in place, intact and able to be successfully logged on that date.  This could be useful information for the cache owner and/or for other potential seekers, e.g. if someone had earlier reported the cache as potentially missing.
2. Some [challenge caches](https://www.geocaching.com/help/index.php?pg=kb.chapter&id=127&pgid=206) may have additional logging requirements that require you to find other caches on specific dates (or e.g. to maintain a streak with at least one cache found per day for a certain number of days).

The challenge part is what sometimes gets people worked up over things like log dates,* since some of those challenges can be genuinely hard, and there can be a certain temptation to "cheat" (e.g. fudging the log date on a cache found just after midnight to avoid breaking a six-month streak) even though, ultimately, it's just a voluntary challenge in a non-competitive game.

If you're not planning on doing any hard challenge caches, there's not much point in being strict about log dates.  Just use whichever date seems the most appropriate.  But I'd generally still suggest using the date when you actually signed the physical log (and which you presumably also wrote in the physical logbook) unless you have some particularly good reason to do otherwise.**  It gives more accurate information to the cache owner, and if you do decide to start doing challenges later, you won't have to worry about whether your old logs *really* qualify or not.

---

<sup>*) What *really* tends to get people worked up is when an inactive cache owner suddenly decides to go through their old logs and delete any that they deem invalid, e.g. because the visitor didn't sign the right logbook, retroactively breaking old streaks etc.  Don't be that person.  While as a cache owner you do have the right to delete invalid logs, please don't do it without warning unless the log is obviously completely bogus.  At least message the person who left the log and give them a chance to fix their mistake.</sup>

<sup>**) As a personal anecdote, I've "misdated" a find log once (that I know of): one of the first caches I found was logged as a group, but the person signing the log forgot to include my nickname.  The cache owner contacted me about this later, after not finding my name in the physical log, so I went back and added my name to the logbook but didn't change the original log date, even though technically I'd only completed the logging requirements once my name was actually in the book.  I think I did post a note about the revisit, though.</sup>

Comment: So quick summary is: always write today's date in the paper log and the online log, even if the cache had been found but not logged earlier.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Pretty much, yes. At least unless you think you have a particularly good reason why an earlier date should count. (See the footnotes for an example. Some other reasons commonly regarded as valid include splitting a formerly shared account and perhaps retroactively logging finds made with someone else — e.g. by a child caching with their parents — before registering your own account. The common thread is that these are all cases where you were present when the cache was found and the log signed, even if your current nickname might not have been written in the physical log.)